# Attach command prompt to jar

Tags: java, windows, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker running a jar at entrypoint,
I was wondering if there was a way i could attach the command prompt to the running jar instance on a windows machine (a bit like "fg" on linux). (it would be great to know if i could detach it from the command promt (a bit like Ctrl+z on linux))

Using docker image:

- adoptopenjdk:11.0.11_9-jdk-hotspot-windowsservercore-1809 as

my entrypoint:

- entrypoint: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar "c:\jars\supcrypto.jar"

Answer (score 0):

"docker attach" seems to be working just enough for me